# How does Eclipse determine which projects to load for a particular workspace?

Tags: eclipse, svn, config, workspace

Does anyone know how Eclipse determines which projects are in a particular workspace? Is there a config file somewhere with this info? I have struggled (in vain) for several hours trying to figure this out.  I'd like to be able to edit this config / check it into SVN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I agree with Thilo that it is not a good idea to put the workspace metadata into your version control system.**

However, in the spirit of answering the question and letting others make their own value decisions:  The directory ${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects should contain one directory for each project that eclipse uses to keep track of where the project is on disk and a whole bunch of other information.

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse works much better if you manage just the individual projects in your version control system.

You can publish the set of projects that make up a workspace as a Project Set File (an XML file that can be created as Export > Team > Project Set), which you could put in your repository. This file contains the repository location for all projects, so that they can be checked out all at once.